# Why does this electret microphone with op-amp circuit cause the negative half wave of the signal to distort?

Tags: operational-amplifier, microphone

[image][image: Circuit used]

This circuit works quite well with low signal levels, but when the RMS AC signal is approximately 0.8 to 1.0 V (measured on pin #1 of the op-amp,) the negative half wave of the sinusoidal signal is distorted so much that you can see it clearly on the oscilloscope. I am not asking how to correct this circuit.  I would like to know the reason for this behavior. This is an existing circuit and I know how it must be changed.

Added: The image from the oscilloscope shows that the "negative" part of the signal is much wider and has a clearly different form. It is not clipping. If  I add voice level to the microphone, clipping starts first on the positive half wave.

Comment: a picture or sketch of the distorted waveform would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the distortion beginning at 0.8 to 1VRMS at the input or output?

It's hard to say definitively without some bench time, but I suspect your biasing scheme.  You have an 8.2K resistor (R2) which doubles as bias and feedback.  The gain is apparently set by this resistor and the current output of the ECM.  This is not a particularly accurate way to set gain, and it's a bit unconventional to bias an ECM with a variable voltage.  It may be when the mic output drives positive, it's starved for bias as the output of the buffer goes negative.

Usually an ECM is biased to a constant DC voltage (many CODECs and other audio components contain a special LDO just to generate a clean, quiet mic bias signal).  Then it is buffered, usually, with the buffer having an input impedance somewhat greater than the ECM output.  (All ECMs I've seen actually include a JFET buffer stage internally, since the voltage and current generated by the electret itself will hardly drive a short length of wire.) wire

Comment: It's not really biased with a variable voltage, the feedback loop will keep the bias exactly at the voltage at the negative terminal, at least within the BW of the op-amp.  And the gain is accurate, but it's technically a transimpedance.  The output voltage is the mic current times the 8.2K.

Comment: True, but a typical bias scheme isn't voltage controlled at the mic terminal, it's more current controlled...the bias current doesn't vary significantly based on the instantaneous output.  In this case, we don't have that reliable source of bias current in all cases.

Comment: Agreed, this is not the typical bias scheme which usually uses a resistor in series for bias, but I don't see that as the issue in this case.

Comment: This was a good hint. The microphone capsule (with JFET inside) can get bias current only through the R2, as I understand. Actually the voltage at the pin #1 of the op amp has both dc and ac (measured dc is 6.2 V). So the bias current for the MIC cannot be considered to be constant, and this is the behavior, when using inverting pin as a signal input pin. Actually the positive half wave is distorted as much but opposite direction. Now I have an understandable explanation, and can give reasonable answer on why these circuits must be fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your virtual ground is formed by R3 and R8, and puts the bias point around 4.9V.

At 25C, with a +/-15V supply, this amplifier is only guaranteed to swing within 3V of the rail.

So 4.9-3V is 1.9V.  It's probable that the amplifier will distort before that point, and with your supply rails at -5V and +10V (due to your bias point being ~5V) it could make the available headroom worse, though there's no data on output swing under those conditions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I should have answered earlier, because I found out the actual reason (as I understand it) in 2020. Sorry for this delay.

Electret microphones should be always biased from a very stable DC voltage via a resistor in series. The main reason, as I understand it, is that the biasing current should be as constant as possible. Some electret microphones have inside a FET whose forward transfer admittance varied strongly when the biasing (FET's drain) current changes. You can see this in the attached graph for a typical FET for electret microphone applications.

Unfortunately, I do not have any datasheet for the microphone used in this device, but this behavior is hard to explain otherwise. In this case varying magnitude of the transadmittance was approximately from -10 to +10 % or of the drain current from -55 to + 55 uA p-p. That is because of varying output voltage in the op amp output pin 1. The 8k2 resistor other pin is connected to the constant voltage, so the only path from which the microphone FET can draw current is via this resistor, so the biasing current changes accordingly. The FET amplification factor is directly related to the forward trans admittance, so when the voltage on the output pin increases, the transadmittance increases as well and accordingly the amplification. When the voltage on the output pin decreases, the amplification decreases also. This explains the waveform on the scope screen.

[image: TF218 Forward Transfer Admittance]

Answer (score 0):

Another problem with your circuit is that the opamp gain is extremely low, then you
must scream at and overload the microphone.

Comment: Actually in the circuit there is the second amplifier stage, which is omitted here as it is not relevant to this problem. It will give needed amplification that can be regulated from 3 to 10.

Comment: With a normal conversation voice level, the output of an electret mic is only 10mV at a 10cm distance. Then the preamp needs a gain of 80 to get your 0.8V opamp output. Digikey sell hundreds of electret mics and each one has a datasheet. Some show 1% distortion at a sound pressure of only 94dB and a max sound level of only100dB that maybe you have. You can make a Linkwitz mod to make the mic have 3 wires and produce low distortion at very loud sound levels.